# Can we change default angular material chip design to rectangle?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I used angular material chips as a tags. So can I change that default circle design to the rectangle design using css?

Comment: Probably, Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: In doc they said " Hint: <mat-basic-chip> receives the mat-basic-chip CSS class in addition to the mat-chip class. " . But I have no idea about that.

Comment: You could override the `mat-basic-chip` class and try to do someting with it.

Comment: You'll have to add `::ng-deep` as a selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In root component css:

`:host ::ng-deep .mat-chip {
  border-radius: 5px;
}`